# Calling an operator with bpy.ops and setting a property that is inside a property group

Tags: python, scripting

I know that one can override an operator's properties when executing it with `bpy.ops.my_operator(my_prop=value)`

eg

```
import bpy


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    
    my_string: bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.my_string)
        return {'FINISHED'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(my_string="I changed the string !")
```

prints `I changed the string !`

Now if I define my operator to use a [Property Group](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html).

How do I override a property that's inside this property group ?

```
import bpy

        
class MyPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_other_string: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="I'm still the same...")


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    
    my_string: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    my_pg: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPG)

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.my_string)
        print(self.my_pg.my_other_string)
        return {'FINISHED'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPG)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)    
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(my_string="I changed the string !")
#    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(my_other_string ??) What do I call ?
```

`bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(my_pg.my_other_string="I changed the other string !")` throws a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: my_pg.my_other_string doesn't work?

Comment: @MartyFouts Nope unfortunately this is forbidden in python...

Comment: Pretty much everything I've tried short of cheating and duplicating MyPG's my_other_string in SimpleOperator fails.  I don't think blender's fooProperty C magic allows what you need.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yeah I think you're right, I've hit a limitation. It's a shame since using property groups can save a lot of duplicate code, especially in operators... I'll have to use a hacky string property to resolve the path and change the value I think. Not ideal but I'll update if it works. Cheers

Comment: Might be worth a feature request on rightclickselect?

Comment: @MartyFouts Yup this would be worthy of a feature request :) But I've kind of given up on RCS so I'll let time decide if this feature sees the light of day or what :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ugly ugly hack and it only works for changing a single property. At this point you might as well ditch the Property Group altogether. But I feel it answers the question nonetheless. One nice thing it does is handling nested property groups :

```
import bpy


class MyNestedPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_other_string: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="I'm still the same...")


class MyPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_nested_pg: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyNestedPG)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    
    my_string: bpy.props.StringProperty("Test")
    my_pg: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPG)
    my_pg_path: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    my_pg_value: bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        path_solver = self.my_pg_path.split(".")
        prop = self
        for i in range(len(path_solver) - 1):
            path = path_solver.pop(0)
            prop = getattr(prop, path)
        setattr(prop, path_solver.pop(0), self.my_pg_value)
        
        print(self.my_pg.my_nested_pg.my_other_string)  # Prints `I changed the string !`
        return {'FINISHED'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyNestedPG)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPG)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)    
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(
        my_pg_path="my_pg.my_nested_pg.my_other_string", 
        my_pg_value="I changed the string !"
    )
```

**Another naughty, naughty hack... Using `exec`**

This does handle multiple properties assignment but it's so ugly my eyes bleed. Well, if it works, it works.

```
import bpy


class MyNestedPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_other_string: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="I'm still the same...")
    yet_another_string: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="I'm still the same...")


class MyPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_nested_pg: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyNestedPG)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    
    my_string: bpy.props.StringProperty("Test")
    my_pg: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPG)
    my_exec_expression: bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        exec(self.my_exec_expression)
        
        print(self.my_pg.my_nested_pg.my_other_string)
        print(self.my_pg.my_nested_pg.yet_another_string)
        return {'FINISHED'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyNestedPG)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPG)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

    expression = 'self.my_pg.my_nested_pg.my_other_string = "I changed the string !"'
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(my_exec_expression=expression)

    expression = '[setattr(self.my_pg.my_nested_pg, "my_other_string", "I changed the string !"), \
        setattr(self.my_pg.my_nested_pg, "yet_another_string", "And yet another changed string !")]'
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(my_exec_expression=expression)
```

This prints :

> I changed the string !

> I'm still the same...

> I changed the string !

> And yet another changed string !